# why does bcc memleak lose malloc information

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, malloc, jemalloc

I'm using bcc-memleak to locate memory leak in my project. But the top command shows that the VIRT increase from 100GB to 200GB and RES from 60GB to 100GB in 10-hours, while memleak shows that only 150MB memory was not released.

I compiled project with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to keep full frame pointer and I got almost every call-stack with outstanding allocations.(-o 3000 means just collect memory older than 30s)

memleak command is `memleak -p {pid} -o 30000 -T 10 20`
(when replacing malloc with jemalloc, add `-O /lib64/libjemalloc.so`)

use std malloc and jemalloc have the same result.

Anyone know how to get more information? or other tools recommend to check memleak.

I have tried jemalloc with prof, but it needs too much cpu and memory, so it didn't solve my problem. Also tried LeakSanitizer, but the result is still only less than 100MB memory leak.

bcc & memleak project: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/memleak.py

UPDATE 1:

`CPPFLAGS=-O2 -Werror=return-type -Werror=uninitialized -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -mavx2 -mf16c`

`LIBADD=-lhiredis -lworkflow -lopenblas -lpugixml -lboost_regex -lboost_system -discovery -lmemcached -loffdb -lz -llzo2 -lprotobuf -lresolv -lpthread -lfmt -lACE`

environment:

- memleak v0.24.0
- gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)
- CentOS Linux 8.2
- kernel: Linux 4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64

Comment: `top` shows how much memory has been `brk`'d or `sbrk`'d from the OS.

Comment: heap management done by standard library is a complex thing. When you release memory in program it doesn't mean the it is immediately returned to operating system (this is what TOP sees).

Comment: You should provide complete configuration: OS name and its version, compiler and its version, all build flags, ... .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my problem, I will add details later :)

Comment: @moore it sounds like you discovered the source of the problem, could you share the details?